# Unable to create/update record using lightning data service

Tags: lightning

I am trying to update FinServ__AssetsAndLiabilities__c record using lightning data service. I am getting below error while trying to save record.

> saving record, error: [{"fieldErrors":{"Id,Name":[{"message":"No
>   access to field Id,Name. Either the field was removed from the entity
>   or access to this field was
>   removed.","fieldApiName":"Id,Name"}]},"pageErrors":[]}]

I have removed all the fields and using only Name, which is a required field. But still I am getting the error. I am able to create/update FinServ__AssetsAndLiabilities__c records using standard page.

Comment: I believe you've written the code wrong. Can you [edit] your question to show the markup and code you've used so far?